# What is the easiest way to define $E_\infty$ algebras in an $\infty$-category?

Tags: higher-category-theory

I'm starting to read Higher Algebra to learn how to define an $E_1=A_{\infty}$
algebra in a monoidal $\infty$-category and how to define a $E_{\infty}$
algebra in a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category. As far as I understand through reading around, the $A_{\infty}$ algebra can be defined without
operads relatively tamely? But to define commutative algebras this is harder? Is this interpretation correct? What is the simplest way (least machinery way?) to define $A_\infty$ or $E_\infty$ algebras? And what is the reason why $E_\infty$ algebras require the operadic machinery? Apologies for this vague question which can probably be found in Higher Algebra.

Comment: A symmetric monoidal infty category is a cocartesian fibration over Fin_*. An E-infty algebra in there is a section which sends ‘collapse maps’ associated to inclusions of finite sets (ie inert maps) to cocartesian lifts thereof.

Comment: Alternatively: a symmetric monoidal infty category is a product preserving presheaf of infty-categories on Span(Fin), and symmetric monoidal functors are natural transformations. You can explicitly build a product-preserving presheaf associated to finite sets under disjoint union. An E_infty algebra is then a symmetric monoidal functor from Fin.

Comment: The issue, as @DylanWilson alludes, is that to define an $E_1$-or $E_\infty$-algebra in an $\infty$-category $C$, you first need a monoidal (resp symmetric monoidal) structure on $C$, and describing this requires at least as much machinery as describing the algebra.

Comment: In the "classical" context of model categories, you start with something like a simplicially enriched 1-category with a monoidal structure, in which case you can think of algebras for an operad over it.  In this context some relatively mild hypotheses imply that A-infinity algebras are essentially the same as associative monoids.

Comment: In the $\infty$-setting, there is no meaningful distinction between A-infinity algebras and associative monoids.

Comment: I guess now I have the question which is why does operads need to be around to define what a symmetric monoidal infinity category is? Is operads also needed if I wanted to define what it means for an infinity category with one object to be commutative? How about a commutative groupoid (if that means sense to ask)?

Comment: @davik you don't necessarily need the machinery of operads in total, but you need some machinery. The issue is that it does not make sense to ask whether a category or a groupoid or something "is" symmetric monoidal (even classically) since one must supply a bunch of structure before one can ask that question. Classically, you can supply a notion of tensor product and a few natural transformations, and then you can ask "is this thing a symmetric monoidal category?". In $\infty$-land, it's structure all the way up, though there are neat ways to package this (a la Segal) that don't

Comment: require an 'operadic' point of view.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand. The commutativity is extra data, given by how the two things are commutative. And the coherentness of these maps requires higher data which I guess is why we need the data of operads

Comment: I think I was curious whether there would be an easy way out to define something like the filling of the two horn is a trivial fibration for infinity categories, but I guess this is unlikely because there is a choice of how the two things are commutative in the data of a commutative infinity category.